# Memory allocation error concatenating zeroes to arrays

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, numpy-ndarray

I have a large 2D numpy array with each sub-array of different length, for example:

```
[[1,2],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I would like to add zeroes at the end of each sub-array smaller than the largest one, something like:

```
[[1,2,0,0],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,0]]
```

To this end, I created the following function to complete the arrays

```
def add_zeroes(arr, limit):
    if len(arr)<limit:
        return np.concatenate([arr, np.zeros(limit-len(arr))])
    else:
        return arr
```

but when I apply it to my array, which consists on a list of 60578 sub-arrays, I get the Memory Error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 8.59 MiB for an array with shape (1126400,) and data type float64
```

I am running on a Core i7 Windows 11, with 16Gb RAM.

Is there a walk around method (more pythonic as well) to complete this task?

Comment: How can you have a large 2D numpy array with different lengths? Do you mean you have a list of lists?

Comment: Indeed, it is a list of lists

Comment: What is `limit`?  Add the code that applies this function to the elements of the list.  You need to track down this (1126400,) shape.

Comment: What shape will the final array have?

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy broadcasting and boolean indexing to convert your sparse matrix as dense matrix:

```
# Input data
sparse = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

# Extract length of each sub lists
length = np.array(list(map(len, sparse)))

# Use broadcasting to find which elements should be copied
mask = np.c_[length] > np.arange(0, max(length))

# Prepare target array (zero-filled)
dense = np.zeros_like(mask, dtype=int)

# Copy flatten data according the mask
dense[mask] = np.concatenate(sparse)
```

Output:

```
>>> dense
array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9, 0]])

>>> mask
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False]])

>>> np.concatenate(sparse)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction about the answer

There is some possibles reasons why it can be happening because the functions is one valid solution to do the problem you comment. I´ll think about to create another solution more efficient if it´s exists but i am not sure about that.

### Possible solution 1

One posible solution is **switch from a 32-bit to a 64-bit** version of Python.

Indeed, 32-bit software, like a 32-bit CPU, can afford a maximum of 4 GB of RAM (2^32). But a **64-bit will afford (2^64)** that is more than 4 GB and it would afford your nearly 9 GB.

#### Ways to check your python version

You can check which version you have by entering the interpreter.

A 64-bit version example would be: Python 3.10.1rc1 (tags/v3.10.1rc1:4082f600a5, Jan 1 2023, 16:18:15) **[MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]**, where [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] means "64-bit Python".

Another way to check your version in windows is execute in `cmd` the next command

```
python -c "import sys;print(\"%x\" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)"
```

or

```
python -c "import sys;print(\"%x\" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**64)"
```

If the response is `true` means that has that number of bits match with your version of python.